# How to randomize Header with Users Agent list?

Tags: python-3.x, random, request-headers

In my script .py i have:

```
    headers = {'Connection': 'keep-alive',
              'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
              'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
              'User-Agent': {agents},
              'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
              'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
              'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8',
              'referer': 'bing.com'}
```

On the .json file

```
    { 
      "user_agent_list": [
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36",
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
      ]
    }
```

and when i send the request:

```
find_file = (grequests.get(url_a, headers={headers}, timeout=None, stream=True, verify=False, allow_redirects=False) for url_a in [f'{site_link}{x}' for x in file_rootl])
```

how i can, randomize headers=**{headers}** for each requests ?  of course  " **for agents in user_agent_list** "

more better:

'User-Agent': **{agents}**,  this i need randomize inside headers...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a random one by having it passed by a random function:

```py
import random

user_agent_list = [
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36",
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
      ]

def get_headers():
    headers = {'Connection': 'keep-alive',
              'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
              'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
              'User-Agent': random.choice(user_agent_list),
              'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
              'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
              'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8',
              'referer': 'bing.com'}
    return headers

#then
find_file = (grequests.get(url_a, headers=get_headers(), timeout=None, stream=True, verify=False, allow_redirects=False) for url_a in [f'{site_link}{x}' for x in file_rootl])
```

where `user_agent_list` has the values imported from the json.

Comment: Also must to correct, need just get_headers(), without { }